# Sporadic Stack Overflow error in java Matcher

Tags: java, regex

I have a some file parser code where I sporadically get stack overflow errors on m.matches() (where m is a Matcher).

I run my app again and it parses the same file with no stack overflow.

It's true my Pattern is a bit complex.  It's basically a bunch of optional zero length positive lookaheads with named groups inside of them so that I can match a bunch of variable name/value pairs irregardless of their order.  But I would expect that if some string would cause a stack overflow error it would always cause it... not just sometimes... any ideas?

A much simplified version of my Pattern 
    `"prefix(?=\\s+user=(?<user>\\S+))?(?=\\s+repo=(?<repo>\\S+))?.*?"`

full regex is...

```
app=github(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+user=(?<user>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+repo=(?<repo>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+remote_address=(?<ip>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+now="(?<time>\S+)\+\d\d:\d\d")?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+url="(?<url>\S+)")?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+referer="(?<referer>\S+)")?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+status=(?<status>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+elapsed=(?<elapsed>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+request_method=(?<requestmethod>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+created_at="(?<createdat>\S+)(?:-|\+)\d\d:\d\d")?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+pull_request_id=(?<pullrequestid>\d+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+at=(?<at>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+fn=(?<fn>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+method=(?<method>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+current_user=(?<user2>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+content_length=(?<contentlength>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+request_category=(?<requestcategory>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+controller=(?<controller>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+action=(?<action>\S+))?.*?
```

Top of stack overflow error stack... (it's about 9800 lines long)

```
Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4480)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3706)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4516)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4697)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4629)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4480)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3706)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4516)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4697)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4629)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4480)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3706)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4516)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4697)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4629)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4480)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3706)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4516)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4697)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4629)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4480)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3706)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4516)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4697)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4629)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4480)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3706)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4516)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4697)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4629)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4480)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3706)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4516)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4697)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4629)
```

example of line I got error on.  (Though I have run it 10 times since and not gotten any error)

```
app=github env=production enterprise=true auth_fingerprint=\"token:6b29527b:9.99.999.99\" controller=\"Api::GitCommits\" path_info=\"/api/v3/repos/XYZ-ABCDE/abcdefg-abc/git/commits/77ae1376f969059f5f1e23cc5669bff8cca50563.diff\" query_string=nil version=v3 auth=oauth current_user=abcdefghijk oauth_access_id=24 oauth_application_id=0 oauth_scopes=\"gist,notifications,repo,user\" route=\"/repositories/:repository_id/git/commits/:id\" org=XYZ-ABCDE oauth_party=personal repo=XYZ-ABCDE/abcdefg-abc repo_visibility=private now=\"2015-09-24T13:44:52+00:00\" request_id=675fa67e-c1de-4bfa-a965-127b928d427a server_id=c31404fc-b7d0-41a1-8017-fc1a6dce8111 remote_address=9.99.999.99 request_method=get content_length=92 content_type=\"application/json; charset=utf-8\" user_agent=nil accept=application/json language=nil referer=nil x_requested_with=nil status=404 elapsed=0.041 url=\"https://git.abc.abcd.abc.com/api/v3/repos/XYZ-ABCDE/abcdefg-abc/git/commits/77ae1376f969059f5f1e23cc5669bff8cca50563.diff\" worker_request_count=77192 request_category=apiapp=github env=production enterprise=true auth_fingerprint=\"token:6b29527b:9.99.999.99\" controller=\"Api::GitCommits\" path_info=\"/api/v3/repos/XYZ-ABCDE/abcdefg-abc/git/commits/9bee255c7b13c589f4e9f1cb2d4ebb5b8519ba9c.diff\" query_string=nil version=v3 auth=oauth current_user=abcdefghijk oauth_access_id=24 oauth_application_id=0 oauth_scopes=\"gist,notifications,repo,user\" route=\"/repositories/:repository_id/git/commits/:id\" org=XYZ-ABCDE oauth_party=personal repo=XYZ-ABCDE/abcdefg-abc repo_visibility=private now=\"2015-09-24T13:44:52+00:00\" request_id=89fcb32e-9ab5-47f7-9464-e5f5cff175e8 server_id=1b74880a-5124-4483-adce-111b60dac111 remote_address=9.99.999.99 request_method=get content_length=92 content_type=\"application/json; charset=utf-8\" user_agent=nil accept=application/json language=nil referer=nil x_requested_with=nil status=404 elapsed=0.024 url=\"https://git.abc.abcd.abc.com/api/v3/repos/XYZ-ABCDE/abcdefg-abc/git/commits/9bee255c7b13c589f4e9f1cb2d4ebb5b8519ba9c.diff\" worker_request_count=76263 request_category=api
```

interestingly... this line seems to be an error... the log seems to put a line break in the wrong place resulting in two log entries being on a single line followed by a blank line.  It's this long line that caused the error... well once anyway... now it runs just fine without stack overflow

Comment: Does the regex work at all? Try `(?s)prefix(?=.*\\s+user=(?<user>\\S+))(?=.*\\s+repo=(?<repo>\\S+))`.You applied `?` quantifier to lookaheads which is meaningless. `.*?` at the end does not match anything, just empty string. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/v6vV7y)

Comment: Your simplified regex won't cause the issue in the question. Please post the real regex or a scaled down regex where **the problem can be reproduced**.

Comment: @nhahtdh  Full regex posted.  Not sure you can reproduce easily... I parse 100,000+ lines just fine then it randomly dies with this error.  Start it up it parses same line just fine.

Comment: @stribizhev Yes - the regex works almost all of the time exactly as desired.  The .* is needed at the end... it matches EVERYTHING in the line basically... because none of the forward lookup's claim anything... and java requires that the WHOLE line be matched.  The ? at the very end... you are right... not really needed... :-)  but it will not work without the .*... try the code below...

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=.*\\s+user=(?<user>\\S+))?");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("user=username");
        if (!m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("not matched without .* at the end");
        }
        
        p = Pattern.compile("(?=.*\\s+user=(?<user>\\S+))?.*");
        m = p.matcher("user=username");
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(" matched with .* at the end");
        }

Comment: I'm completely sure the problem is caused by `(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*`. On a long string, it will repeat many times, and each repetition for the outer alternation has to be stored on stack, leading to stack overflow. What is the input you are trying to parse? The query string in URL? Config file?

Comment: @nhahtdh I am parsing unicorn logs.  I'm still confused why I would get stack overflow only sporadically.  It seems like every time it parses a particular it should either stack overflow or not... but not stack overflow once and then parse fine the next time.

Comment: @Ben: It depends on the length of the string, and the position of the field in the line. If the field is not found, or thousands of characters away from `app=github`, then StackOverflowError can occur. It would be great if you can provide an example string - since I can't give advice based on the regex alone for this case.

Comment: @nhahtdh I updated question description with example line... see bottom of question description

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 ways to fix your problem:

- Parse the input string properly and get the key values from the `Map`.

  **I strongly recommend using this method**, since the code will be much cleaner, and we no longer have to watch the limit on the input size.
- Modify the existing regex to greatly reduce the impact of the implementation flaw which causes `StackOverflowError`.

### Parse the input string

You can parse the input string with the following regex:

```
\G\s*+(\w++)=([^\s"]++|"[^"]*+")(?:\s++|$)
```

- All quantifiers are made possessive (`*+` instead of `*`, `++` instead of `+`), since the pattern I wrote doesn't need backtracking.
- You can find the basic regex `(\w++)=([^\s"]++|"[^"]*+")` to match key-value pairs in the middle.
- `\G` is to make sure the match starts from where the last match leaves off. It is used to prevent the engine from "bump-along" when it fails to match.
- `\s*+` and `(?:\s++|$)` are for consuming excess spaces. I specify `(?:\s++|$)` instead of `\s*+` to prevent `key="value"key=value` from being recognized as valid input.

The full example code can be found below:

```
private static final Pattern KEY_VALUE = Pattern.compile("\\G\\s*+(\\w++)=([^\\s\"]++|\"[^\"]*+\")(?:\\s++|$)");

public static Map<String, String> parseKeyValue(String kvString) {
    Matcher matcher = KEY_VALUE.matcher(kvString);

    Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<String, String>();
    int lastIndex = -1;

    while (matcher.find()) {
        output.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
        lastIndex = matcher.end();
    }

    // Make sure that we match everything from the input string
    if (lastIndex != kvString.length()) {
        return null;
    }

    return output;
}
```

You might want to unquote the values, depending on your requirement.

You can also rewrite the function to pass a `List` of keys you want to extract, and pick them out in the while loop as you go to avoid storing keys that you don't care about.

### Modify the regex

The problem is due to the outer repetition `(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*` being implemented with recursion, leading to `StackOverflowError` when the input string is long enough.

Specifically, in each repetition, it matches either a quoted token, or *a single non-quoted character*. As a result, the stack grows linearly with the number of non-quoted characters and blows up.

You can replace all instance of `(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*` with `[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*`. The stack will now grow linearly as the number of quoted tokens, so StackOverflowError will not occur, unless you have thousands of quoted tokens in the input string.

```
Pattern KEY_CAPTURE = Pattern.compile("app=github(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+user=(?<user>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+repo=(?<repo>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+remote_address=(?<ip>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+now=\"(?<time>\\S+)\\+\\d\\d:\\d\\d\")?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+url=\"(?<url>\\S+)\")?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+referer=\"(?<referer>\\S+)\")?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+status=(?<status>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+elapsed=(?<elapsed>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+request_method=(?<requestmethod>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+created_at=\"(?<createdat>\\S+)(?:-|\\+)\\d\\d:\\d\\d\")?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+pull_request_id=(?<pullrequestid>\\d+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+at=(?<at>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+fn=(?<fn>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+method=(?<method>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+current_user=(?<user2>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+content_length=(?<contentlength>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+request_category=(?<requestcategory>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+controller=(?<controller>\\S+))?(?=[^\"]*(?:\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*\\s+action=(?<action>\\S+))?");
```

It follows equivalent expansion of the regex `(A|B)*` → `A*(BA*)*`. Which to use as A or B depends on their number of repetitions - whichever repeats more should be A and the other should be B.

### Deep diving into the implementation

`StackOverflowError` in `Pattern` is a known problem, which could happen when your pattern contains a repetition of a *non-deterministic*<sup>1</sup> capturing/non-capturing group, which is the subpattern `(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*` in your case.

<sup><sup>1</sup> This is a terminology used in the source code of `Pattern`, which is *probably* intended to be an indicator that the pattern has fixed length. However, the implementation considers alternation `|` to be non-deterministic, regardless of the actual pattern.</sup>

Greedy or lazy repetition of a non-deterministic capturing/non-capturing group is compiled into `Loop`/`LazyLoop` classes, which implement repetition by recursion. As a result, such pattern is extremely prone to trigger `StackOverflowError`, especially when the group contains a branch where only a single character is matched at a time.

On the other hand, *deterministic*<sup>2</sup> repetition, possessive repetition, and repetition of *independent* group `(?>...)` (a.k.a. *atomic* group or *non-backtracking* group) are compiled into `Curly`/`GroupCurly` classes, which processes the repetition with loop in most cases, so there will be no `StackOverflowError`.

<sup><sup>2</sup> The repeated pattern is a character class, or a fixed length capturing/non-capturing group without any alternation</sup>

You can see how a fragment of your original regex is compiled below. Take note of the problematic part, which starts with `Loop`, and compare it to your stack trace.

```
app=github(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+user=(?<user>\S+))?(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*\s+repo=(?<repo>\S+))?
BnM. Boyer-Moore (BMP only version) (length=10)
  app=github
Ques. Greedy optional quantifier
  Pos. Positive look-ahead
    GroupHead. local=0
    Prolog. Loop wrapper
    Loop [1889ca51]. Greedy quantifier {0,2147483647}
      GroupHead. local=1
      Branch. Alternation (in printed order):
        CharProperty.complement. S̄:
          BitClass. Match any of these 1 character(s):
            "
        ---
        Single. Match code point: U+0022 QUOTATION MARK
        Curly. Greedy quantifier {0,2147483647}
          CharProperty.complement. S̄:
            BitClass. Match any of these 1 character(s):
              "
          Node. Accept match
        Single. Match code point: U+0022 QUOTATION MARK
        ---
      BranchConn [7e41986c]. Connect branches to sequel.
      GroupTail [47e1b36]. local=1, group=0. --[next]--> Loop [1889ca51]
    Curly. Greedy quantifier {1,2147483647}
      Ctype. POSIX (US-ASCII): SPACE
      Node. Accept match
    Slice. Match the following sequence (BMP only version) (length=5)
      user=
    GroupHead. local=3
    Curly. Greedy quantifier {1,2147483647}
      CharProperty.complement. S̄:
        Ctype. POSIX (US-ASCII): SPACE
      Node. Accept match
    GroupTail [732c7887]. local=3, group=2. --[next]--> GroupTail [6c9d2223]
    GroupTail [6c9d2223]. local=0, group=0. --[next]--> Node [4ea5d7f2]
    Node. Accept match
  Node. Accept match
Ques. Greedy optional quantifier
  Pos. Positive look-ahead
    GroupHead. local=4
    Prolog. Loop wrapper
    Loop [402c5f8a]. Greedy quantifier {0,2147483647}
      GroupHead. local=5
      Branch. Alternation (in printed order):
        CharProperty.complement. S̄:
          BitClass. Match any of these 1 character(s):
            "
        ---
        Single. Match code point: U+0022 QUOTATION MARK
        Curly. Greedy quantifier {0,2147483647}
          CharProperty.complement. S̄:
            BitClass. Match any of these 1 character(s):
              "
          Node. Accept match
        Single. Match code point: U+0022 QUOTATION MARK
        ---
      BranchConn [21347df0]. Connect branches to sequel.
      GroupTail [7d382897]. local=5, group=0. --[next]--> Loop [402c5f8a]
    Curly. Greedy quantifier {1,2147483647}
      Ctype. POSIX (US-ASCII): SPACE
      Node. Accept match
    Slice. Match the following sequence (BMP only version) (length=5)
      repo=
    GroupHead. local=7
    Curly. Greedy quantifier {1,2147483647}
      CharProperty.complement. S̄:
        Ctype. POSIX (US-ASCII): SPACE
      Node. Accept match
    GroupTail [71f111ba]. local=7, group=4. --[next]--> GroupTail [9c304c7]
    GroupTail [9c304c7]. local=4, group=0. --[next]--> Node [4ea5d7f2]
    Node. Accept match
  Node. Accept match
LastNode.
Node. Accept match
```

Comment: Wow....  Thanks!  Very complete and informative answer! I like your preferred suggestion... much cleaner and more flexible! It took me a while to figure out how this works... [^"]*(?:"[^\"]*"[^"]*)* ...I am curious... would this do the same sort of thing in preventing as many recursions?  (?:[^"]++|"[^"]*")*

Comment: @Ben: It won't work in your case, since you need the engine to backtrack to pick up the kay-value pair you want to match.

Comment: @nhahtdh, extremely informative! wish i could give more +1's :)

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks!  ah... so possessive is permanently possessive even if it's wrapped in a non-possessive group?  Like I was thinking the possessiveness would make each iteration of the non-cap group take as many non-quotes as possible in a single iteration, but that each iteration of the non-cap group as a whole would still backtrack once it reached the end, including the possessive matches contained within.  Geese... when regex's get complex I suddenly feel so clueless and like I should grasp this better...

Comment: @Ben - You actually don't want to backtrack in this case. Using an atomic group is your best bet. I updated with a new regex, give it a try.

Comment: @nhahtdh I just noticed something.  In the second part where you talk about modifying the original regex... you said... You can replace all instance of (?:[^"]|"[^"]*")* with [^"]*(?:"[^\"]*"[^"]*)*.... Is it just me or should the backslash in the second part not be there... I mean... it will need to be there in the end when I actually have it in a string in java... but so will all the quotes.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks. I forgot to remove it. Technically, the meaning is the same (in raw form), but it would be confusing to read.

Answer (score 3):

Final answer:

Move this `(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*` functionality into an alternation group with
the others.

Sample:  https://ideone.com/YuVcMg

It can't be broken!

---

> A side note - I noticed you said you deleted a newline and ended up with
>   the end of one record being without a separator between the next,
>   like this `request_category=apiapp=github`
>
> That is ok, but these regexes will mostly blow by it when it hits the
>   `\S+`.
>
> For that reason, it is better to replace `\S+` with `(?:(?!app=github)\S)+`,
>   which is not done in the below regex.
>   Here is the one below with that added:

```
"(?s)app=github(?>\\s+user=(?<user>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+repo=(?<repo>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+remote_address=(?<ip>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+now=\\\\?\"(?<time>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)\\+\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\\\?\"|\\s+url=\\\\?\"(?<url>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)\\\\?\"|\\s+referer=\\\\?\"(?<referer>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)\\\\?\"|\\s+status=(?<status>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+elapsed=(?<elapsed>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+request_method=(?<requestmethod>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+created_at=\\\\?\"(?<createdat>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)[-+]\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\\\?\"|\\s+pull_request_id=(?<pullrequestid>\\d+)|\\s+at=(?<at>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+fn=(?<fn>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+method=(?<method>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+current_user=(?<user2>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+content_length=(?<contentlength>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+request_category=(?<requestcategory>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+controller=(?<controller>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\\s+action=(?<action>(?:(?!app=github)\\S)+)|\"[^\"]*\"|(?!app=github).)+"
```

> And a link to that sample using it:  https://ideone.com/hdwufO

---

**Regex**

Raw:

```
(?s)app=github(?>\s+user=(?<user>\S+)|\s+repo=(?<repo>\S+)|\s+remote_address=(?<ip>\S+)|\s+now=\\?"(?<time>\S+)\+\d\d:\d\d\\?"|\s+url=\\?"(?<url>\S+)\\?"|\s+referer=\\?"(?<referer>\S+)\\?"|\s+status=(?<status>\S+)|\s+elapsed=(?<elapsed>\S+)|\s+request_method=(?<requestmethod>\S+)|\s+created_at=\\?"(?<createdat>\S+)[-+]\d\d:\d\d\\?"|\s+pull_request_id=(?<pullrequestid>\d+)|\s+at=(?<at>\S+)|\s+fn=(?<fn>\S+)|\s+method=(?<method>\S+)|\s+current_user=(?<user2>\S+)|\s+content_length=(?<contentlength>\S+)|\s+request_category=(?<requestcategory>\S+)|\s+controller=(?<controller>\S+)|\s+action=(?<action>\S+)|"[^"]*"|(?!app=github).)+
```

Stringed:

```
"(?s)app=github(?>\\s+user=(?<user>\\S+)|\\s+repo=(?<repo>\\S+)|\\s+remote_address=(?<ip>\\S+)|\\s+now=\\\\?\"(?<time>\\S+)\\+\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\\\?\"|\\s+url=\\\\?\"(?<url>\\S+)\\\\?\"|\\s+referer=\\\\?\"(?<referer>\\S+)\\\\?\"|\\s+status=(?<status>\\S+)|\\s+elapsed=(?<elapsed>\\S+)|\\s+request_method=(?<requestmethod>\\S+)|\\s+created_at=\\\\?\"(?<createdat>\\S+)[-+]\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\\\?\"|\\s+pull_request_id=(?<pullrequestid>\\d+)|\\s+at=(?<at>\\S+)|\\s+fn=(?<fn>\\S+)|\\s+method=(?<method>\\S+)|\\s+current_user=(?<user2>\\S+)|\\s+content_length=(?<contentlength>\\S+)|\\s+request_category=(?<requestcategory>\\S+)|\\s+controller=(?<controller>\\S+)|\\s+action=(?<action>\\S+)|\"[^\"]*\"|(?!app=github).)+"
```

Formatted:

```
 (?s)
 app = github
 (?>
      \s+ 
      user =
      (?<user> \S+ )                # (1)
   |  
      \s+  repo =
      (?<repo> \S+ )                # (2)
   |  
      \s+ remote_address =
      (?<ip> \S+ )                  # (3)
   |  
      \s+ now= \\? "
      (?<time> \S+ )                # (4)
      \+ \d\d : \d\d \\? "
   |  
      \s+ url = \\? "
      (?<url> \S+ )                 # (5)
      \\? "
   |  
      \s+ referer = \\? "
      (?<referer> \S+ )             # (6)
      \\? "
   |  
      \s+ status =
      (?<status> \S+ )              # (7)
   |  
      \s+ elapsed =
      (?<elapsed> \S+ )             # (8)
   |  
      \s+ request_method =
      (?<requestmethod> \S+ )       # (9)
   |  
      \s+ created_at = \\? "
      (?<createdat> \S+ )           # (10)
      [-+] 
      \d\d : \d\d \\? "
   |  
      \s+ pull_request_id =
      (?<pullrequestid> \d+ )       # (11)
   |  
      \s+ at=
      (?<at> \S+ )                  # (12)
   |  
      \s+ fn=
      (?<fn> \S+ )                  # (13)
   |  
      \s+ method =
      (?<method> \S+ )              # (14)
   |  
      \s+ current_user =
      (?<user2> \S+ )               # (15)
   |  
      \s+ content_length =
      (?<contentlength> \S+ )       # (16)
   |  
      \s+ request_categor y=
      (?<requestcategory> \S+ )     # (17)
   |  
      \s+ controller =
      (?<controller> \S+ )          # (18)
   |  
      \s+ action =
      (?<action> \S+ )              # (19)
   |  
      " [^"]* "                     # None of the above, give quotes a chance
   |  
      (?! app = github )            # Failsafe, consume a character, advance by 1
      . 
 )+
```

Comment: Both of your methods are susceptible to StackOverflowError, if the string has more unquoted tokens. This part `(?:(?!\\s*app=github)[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*?` in particular is the cause.

Comment: @nhahtdh - I've posted some performance stats for both regex. I have not seen any stack overflow errors, but I don't have Java, so was tested using Boost and Perl separately. Maybe you could use the test that I've explained in the update to demonstrate an overflow, or timeout..

Comment: If indeed Java uses the stack to push each pass through a group with an alternation, then if it never unwinds, there would be an overflow. I would say since alternations are the heart of Regex, probably Java should be scrapped in lieu of something else.. I'm still not convinced this was the cause of the error. I'm inclined to believe it was a timeout in disguise.

Comment: Well, it's possible to look at it as a way to prevent excessive use of memory to perform a match, since you need to keep track of the number of characters per repetition to backtrack when the repeated pattern is not fixed length ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161874/why-is-performance-of-xy5-slower-than-xyxyxyxyxy/28171025#28171025)). Java doesn't do anything to prevent catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: As for SOE, here is a test on ideone: https://ideone.com/sSA1cG. Your pattern will use one stack frame per character outside quoted string, so it will get SOE when the string is longer.

Comment: @nhahtdh - Quite interesting. The only thing that seems to stop it is atomic groups. Try this https://ideone.com/YuVcMg I just moved the functionality down into an atomic cluster group. But, quite frankly, there can be no backtracking if it were a regular group. So, Java bite's !!

Comment: The atomic group seems to fix the issue completely, since the generated regex uses Curly instead of Loop for the outer repetition. http://pastebin.com/6Fe5vzNr I confirm this solution is safe to use.

Comment: @sln  "whats an "atomic cluster group"?   Also I am confused how your regex is making sure it's not matching a key value pair that happens to be in a quoted string.  Though admittedly I have only glanced at is so far, and don't fully understand what's going on yet...

Comment: @sln You mentioned how my example had "apiapp=git" Yea... so turns out the logs I am parsing sometimes miss a linebreak... What I wound up doing is checking the string first, to make sure it's not really two lines, and then breaking it into two if it was... this caused the SOE to go away without changing anything... being super busy, I left the code how it is even though it's inefficient because if it aint broke dont fix it.  Though I appreciate all the activity on this question.. it's thought provoking and helping me learn regex better.. and in case my code breaks I have a few options here...

Comment: @Ben - The _atomic_ groups are like ordinary groups except that any matched content from the expression contained within will not be given back to external backtracking. Also, matching is done left to right at the given position. And alternations are handled left to right (or, top to bottom), so putting the `"[^"]*"` after all the other ones, lets it match a full quoted part. Finally, the last in the group is a single character `.`. These two together consume all the text up to a key/value pair you want to match, which gets first chance in the alternation order.

Comment: @Ben - Second question. I added the regex and link that take care of adjacent records, so it won't blow past, into the next record. Now, it doesn't matter if a whitespace is between records. Note- the techniques I use come from years of experience. But, I've learned that Java has problems that may not exist on other engines. There is always a workaround though, but it would be a hassle to have to do it all the time.

Comment: @sln Thanks!  I am perhaps being dense here... your description of an atomic group sounds like possessiveness (i.e. adding a + after your quantifier to not allow back tracking).  Is an atomic group then just a group that has a possessive quantifier?  Oh... hmmm... I was just looking up to see what "?>" was... an INDEPENDENT non-cap group... I was going to ask what does the "independent" mean.  i.e. what's the diff between ?> and ?: ...  perhaps it's the same answer to both of these... is ?> just making the group possessive/atomic/non-backtracking?

Comment: @sln  If so... is there technically a difference between using ?> at the start of a group vs making all the quantifiers inside the group greedy "manually" with a +?

Comment: @Ben: Ignoring the terminology "independent group" (which is how `(?>...)` is called in Java), `(?>...)` simply disallow backtracking into the group once you exit the group - you can only backtrack to before the group all at once. The purpose of `(?>...)` here is to avoid backtracking into each of the key-value pair once you have matched it.

Comment: @sln Ahhhh... Thanks!  so just to make sure I understand... ?> will allow you to backtrack while within the group... but once you exit the group it's locked in place as a single token in terms of backtracking.  You can only backtrack across the whole group at once.

Comment: @Ben - Yes, basically `(?>.|.|.)+` is the same as `(?>.)(?>.)(?>.)(?>.)(?>.)(?>.)(?>.) on and on...`