# WSO2 error when converting Text message to o Siddhi Event

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am using **WSO2SP version 4.3.0** with regex extension : **siddhi-execution-regex-4.1.2.jar**. My code was working fine but whenever i restart my wso2sp instance i start getting error "**Exception occurred when converting Text message to Siddhi Event in the stream transactionstream1 of siddhi text input mapper. java.lang.StackOverflowError** " 
I have to restart wso2sp multiple times to get this working,which is not a viable solution. I am also sending text message via http using extension **siddhi-io-http-1.0.40.jar**. Text map extension : **siddhi-map-text-1.1.2.jar** and **siddhi-map-text-1.0.22.jar**

Test source :

```
@source(type = 'http', receiver.url = 'http://localhost:5005/text',
@map(type='text',fail.on.missing.attribute='false', regex.A=""""(after)":("(\\"|[^"])*"|\[("(\\"|[^"])*"(,"(\\"|[^"])*")*)?\])""",
                @attributes(payload = 'A[2]')))
define stream transactionstream1(payload string);
```

Test Text:

```
curl -X POST \
    http://localhost:5005/text \
    -H 'content-type: application/json' \
 -d '{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"id"}],"optional":false,"name":"db.db.Key"},"payload":{"id":"{ \"$oid\" : \"dafeafwe3\"}"}} {"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Json","version":1,"field":"after"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Json","version":1,"field":"patch"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"version"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"connector"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"name"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Enum","version":1,"parameters":{"allowed":"true,last,false"},"default":"false","field":"snapshot"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"db"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"rs"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"collection"},{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"ord"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"h"}],"optional":false,"name":"io.debezium.connector.mongo.Source","field":"source"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"op"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"ts_ms"}],"optional":false,"name":"db.db.collection.Envelope"},"payload":{"after":"{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"54444342fdsfsdfs\"},\"code\": \"42432432423\",\"name\": \"name1\",\"desc\": \"description\",\"transRefId\": \"cgvvjbjhvjy6979yjbv\",\"origAmount\": 1000,\"amount\": 1000,\"currency\": \"USD\",\"redeemedCashcode\": \"\",\"sender\": {\"id\": \"342edesfsfes\",\"name\": \"rose\",\"phone\": \"123456789\"},\"receiver\": {\"id\": \"fr3wfwrw342\",\"name\": \"daass\",\"phone\": \"453452423\",\"client\": \"CLIENT2\"}}}'
```

Part of Stack trace:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.text.sourcemapper.TextSourceMapper}Exception occurred when converting Text message {"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"id"}],"optional":false,"name":"db.db.Key"},"payload":{"id":"{ \"$oid\" : \"dafeafwe3\"}"}}   {"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Json","version":1,"field":"after"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Json","version":1,"field":"patch"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"version"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"connector"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"name"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Enum","version":1,"parameters":{"allowed":"true,last,false"},"default":"false","field":"snapshot"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"db"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"rs"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"collection"},{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"ord"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"h"}],"optional":false,"name":"io.debezium.connector.mongo.Source","field":"source"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"op"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"ts_ms"}],"optional":false,"name":"db.db.collection.Envelope"},"payload":{"after":"{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"54444342fdsfsdfs\"},\"code\": \"42432432423\",\"name\": \"name1\",\"desc\": \"description\",\"transRefId\": \"cgvvjbjhvjy6979yjbv\",\"origAmount\": 1000,\"amount\": 1000,\"currency\": \"USD\",\"redeemedCashcode\": \"\",\"sender\": {\"id\": \"342edesfsfes\",\"name\": \"rose\",\"phone\": \"123456789\"},\"receiver\": {\"id\": \"fr3wfwrw342\",\"name\": \"daass\",\"phone\": \"453452423\",\"client\": \"CLIENT2\"}}},"op":"r","ts_ms":1575862492251}} to Siddhi Event in the stream transactionstream1 of siddhi text input mapper. java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3779)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3779)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3779)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3779)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3779)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice.match(Pattern.java:3974)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3779)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
```

Is there a version compatible issue ? How do i resolve this permanently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this behavior is related to Java notoriously doesn't liking alternations in certain circumstances where there are potential backtrack problems.

So, this part ("(\"|[^"])*"|[("(\"|[^"])*"(,"(\"|[^"])*")*)?])" creates an undo burden on the backtrack mechanism.

Please try updating the regex as below to reduce the impact of the implementation flaw which causes **StackOverflowError**.

```
(after)":("(\\"|[|]|[^"])*+")
```

Please refer [Sporadic Stack Overflow error in java Matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876288/sporadic-stack-overflow-error-in-java-matcher/32988490) for more details.